# How to read data from URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to read data from URL using JavaScript.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const url = 'someurl';
  React.useEffect(() => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => JSON.stringify(res))
        .then(data => setData(data);
        });
    if (data) {
      console.log('data', data);
    }

  }
```

logging the data state would give the result like below,

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "results": [{
      "title": "title1",
      "characters": [
        "character1",
      ],

    },
    {
      "title": "title2",
      "characters": [
        "character3",
      ],

    },
  ]
}
```

How can I read results object from URL?

Comment: Are we to assume that you're *not* getting data like that by reading data from state? If so, you have to remember that `fetch` is asynchronous, as is `setData`. You have to wait until both processes complete before you can read the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: try console.logging outside useEffect

Answer (score 1):

You don't do

```
fetch(url)
   .then(res => JSON.stringify(res))
   //...
```

Instead you do

```
fetch(url)
   .then(res => res.json())
   //...
```

Reason being that `res` is a `Response` [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which contains more than just the data you're interested in (the response body).

Comment: using this for some reason gives me [object object]

Comment: What do you mean by "gives me"? Is this the output of `console.log()`?

Comment: That's maybe fine depending on how smart your browser is. You can do `console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data))` in case your browser isn't very smart.

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => setData(data))
```